# child process exited with exit code 1

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I am running a code for loading datasets into tables with psql, and the
make the following steps

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mimic;
CREATE DATABASE mimic OWNER postgres;

set search_path to mimiciii;

\c mimic;

\i C:/Tools/mimic-code-master/buildmimic/postgres/postgres_create_tables.sql

\set ON_ERROR_STOP 1

\set mimic_data_dir 'C:/mimic-iii-clinical-database-1.4'
```

when i run this command

```
\i C:/Tools/mimic-code-master/buildmimic/postgres/postgres_load_data_7zip.sql
```

error shows:
so ADMISSIONS.csv.gz: child process exited with exit code 1

What should I do to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 and 9.5 are [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm going to say it is whatever is in `postgres_load_data_7zip.sql`. You will need to update the question with that information.